# making http request depending on the result of a previous call

Tags: angularjs

How to make this more elegant. I found many example to make multiples request using `$q.all()` but nothing about making a request depending on the result of a previous call.

```
    $scope.data = [];
    $scope.data2 = [];

    $http({
        url: '/some/url',
        method: "GET"
    })
    .success(function(data){
        $scope.data = data
    })
    .then(function(result)){

        $http({
            url: '/some/url2',
            method: "GET",
            params: {
                param    : result.data.param //data returned by the fist call
            }
        })
        .success(function(data){
            $scope.data2 = data
        })

    })
```

Comment: Questions about how to improve already working code are usually submitted to [Code Review Stack Exchange](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `.then` for this purpose, without using `.success` and `.error` callbacks. `.then` are chainable, so you can make new http requests based on data of the previous call:

```
$scope.data = [];
$scope.data2 = [];

$http({
    url: '/some/url',
    method: "GET"
})
.then(function(data) {
    $scope.data = data.data;
    $http({
        url: '/some/url2',
        method: "GET",
        params: {
            param: data.data.param //data returned by the fist call
        }
    })
    .then(function(data){
        $scope.data2 = data.data;
    })
});
```

Also notice changing to `data.data` in the response.

Comment: Thanks but I'm looking for something more elegant.. Your answer is pretty much the same as what I'm doing right now.

Comment: This is how you do it, can be more elegant with a service or a function

Comment: @Lorenzo A more elegant way would maybe depend on the specific use case. But this seems to be the most general and accepted way to do so.

Comment: When I need to paginate through a response, or make more requests with the received data I usually call if recursively. You need to create a promise with `$q`  pass the `deferred = $q.defer()` to the function e.g. `function fetchData(deferred, url, params)` and resolve it when the last request is done.

Answer (score 0):

To me it is more elegant to **return** the data and **chain** from it.

```
//first scope variable not needed
//$scope.data = [];
$scope.data2 = [];

$http({ url: '/some/url',
        method: "GET"
}).then( function(response){
    return response.data;
}).then( function(someData){
    var httpPromise = 
          $http({ url: '/some/url2',
                  method: "GET",
                  params: {
                    param: someData.param //someData chained
                  }
               });
    return httpPromise;
}).then (function(promiseResult){
    $scope.data2 = promiseResult.data
});
```

I avoid the `.success` and `.error` methods for two reasons: They **ignore return values** and they are **deprecated**. For more information on tbe deprecation of `.success` and `.error`, see the [AngularJS $http Service API Reference -- deprecation notice](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#deprecation-notice).

### Chaining promises

Because calling the `then` method of a promise returns a new derived promise, it is easily possible to create a chain of promises:

```
promiseB = promiseA.then(function(result) {
  return result + 1;
});

// promiseB will be resolved immediately after promiseA is resolved and its value
// will be the result of promiseA incremented by 1
```

It is possible to create chains of any length and since a promise can be resolved with another promise (which will defer its resolution further), it is possible to pause/defer resolution of the promises at any point in the chain. This makes it possible to implement powerful APIs like `$http`'s response interceptors.

-- [AngularJS $q Service API Reference - chaining promises](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#chaining-promises)